# Is it possible to transpose tabular data in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to change, for example,

```
1   0   3   4   3   0  
2   12  56  3   2   2  
3   4   21  0   5   0  
4   9   14  13  6   56
```

into

```
1   2   3   4  
0   12  4   9  
3   56  21  14  
4   3   0   13  
3   2   5   6  
0   2   0   56
```

Is it possible to do this in notepad++?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question (doing it in Notepad++), but this can be done in Excel (in case you are flexible with the software used for the task): https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2. Based on a quick Google search, I don't know that it is possible to do this in Notepad++ (here they recommend using a Python script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045364/transpose-function-in-notepad)

Comment: The table in the question was made using excel, I need to know if this is possible specifically in notepad++

Comment: [so] duplicate [Transpose function in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20045364)