# Notepad++ - turning a long file into columns

Tags: notepad++, text-formatting

I have a long file I want to stick in some other editor for later printing.
The file is of the format:

```
line1
line2
line3
...
line456
...
```

Seeing that all the lines are short, I wouldn't mind turning this into two (or even three) columns:

```
line1   line21   line41
line2   line22   line42

line3   line23   line43
.......
```

Can it be done in any efficient way?
Let's assume the editor I'm pasting it into doesn't have some easy WYSIWYG column mode.

Comment: What tools do you have available and are willing to use? This may be scriptable using PowerShell, awk, or some other scripting language or tool...

Comment: Oh, so it can't be done with vanilla Notepad++?

Comment: What are the rules to put `line1`, `line21` and `line41` on the same line? Where are `line11`, `line31` and `line51`? What happens to `line456`? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1616768/edit) and add more infos and test cases.

Comment: May be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/949697/is-it-possible-to-transpose-tabular-data-in-notepad

Comment: It does not appear to be doable in vanilla (unmodified) np++, but if you're competent to write code in python, there appears to be a plugin ([PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)) that may allow you to do this within the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use Regular expression to achieve what you are trying to do. Here is one way to do it.

## FOR TWO COLUMNS

SEARCH FOR:   `^(.*)$\r\n^(.*)$` and

REPLACE WITH: `\1 \2`

## FOR THREE COLUMNS

SEARCH FOR:   `^(.*)$\r\n^(.*)$\r\n^(.*)$` and

REPLACE WITH: `\1 \2 \3`

Here is a quick video that demonstrate these steps.
(https://youtu.be/y1PcKUhDi14)

**Disclaimer**: This video is from my YouTube channel, which demonstrates all steps required to answer this question.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should (re)read the question, have you seen the example?

Comment: @Toto Sorry, I did not understand completely that he is trying to use multi Column view for printing.

Comment: Please, avoid to answer unclear question.